# Find the asymptote and the upper bound for $1\big/ \ln\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)$ as $x\to\infty$.

Tags: limits, logarithms, asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds

I need to show that $\left[\ln\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)\right]^{-1}$ asymptotically approaches to a line from below that I should determine, and hence, show that $\frac{x}{2} > \left[\ln\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)\right]^{-1}$ for $x>1$.  I would be very happy if someone helps. Thank you.

Comment: By $^{-1}$ do you mean multiplicative inverse or inverse function?

Comment: I meant reciprocal. Thanks !!!

Comment: but why do you need that inequality?

Answer (score 3):

Fix $x > 1$ and write $\varphi(t) = \frac{1}{x+t}$. Since $\varphi_x$ is strictly convex, it follows from the [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) that

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2} \log\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)
= \frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^{1} \varphi_x(t) \, \mathrm{d}t
> \varphi_x \left( \frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^{1} t \, \mathrm{d}t \right)
= \frac{1}{x}
\end{align*}

On the other hand, again by the strict convexity of $\varphi_x$,

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2} \log\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)
= \frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^{1} \varphi_x(t) \, \mathrm{d}t
< \frac{\varphi_x(-1) + \varphi_x(1)}{2}
= \frac{x}{x^2-1}.
\end{align*}

Altogether, it follows that

$$ \frac{x}{2} - \frac{1}{2x} < \left[\log\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)\right]^{-1} < \frac{x}{2} $$

for all $x > 1$.

---

**Addendum.** It is easy to check that the above function admits the Laurent expansion of the form

$$ \left[\log\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)\right]^{-1} = \frac{x}{2} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_{2n+1}}{x^{2n+1}} $$

as $x\to\infty$. Now here comes a hard part: $\texttt{Mathematica}$ seems to suggests $a_{2n+1} > 0$ for all $n \geq 0$. For instance,

$$
a_1 = \frac{1}{6}, \quad
a_3 = \frac{2}{45}, \quad
a_5 = \frac{22}{945}, \quad
a_7 = \frac{214}{14175}, \quad
a_9 = \frac{5098}{467775}, \quad \cdots. $$

It will be interesting to be able to prove it, although I have no good idea to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\ln (1+t)<t~\forall~t>0$,
\begin{align*}
\ln\left(1+\frac2{x-1}\right)&<\frac2{x-1}~\forall~ x>1\\
\frac1{\ln\left(1+\frac2{x-1}\right)}&>\frac{x-1}2~\forall~ x>1\tag{1}\\
\end{align*}
Consider $f(x)=\frac x2-\frac1{\ln\left(1+\frac2{x-1}\right)}~\forall~ x>1$.
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to1}f(x)&=\frac12\\
\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x\ln\left(1+\frac2{x-1}\right)-2}{2\ln\left(1+\frac2{x-1}\right)}=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{(t+1)\ln\left(1+\frac2t\right)-2}{2\ln\left(1+\frac2t\right)}\\&=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{(t+1)\left(\frac2t-\frac2{t^2}+O(t^2)\right)-2}{\frac4t}=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{(t+1)\left(1-\frac1t\right)-t}{2}=0\\
&\Rightarrow \boxed{\frac1{\ln\left(1+\frac2{x-1}\right)}\to\frac x2\text{ as }x\to\infty,~\forall~ x>1}\\
f^\prime(x)&=\frac12-\frac2{(x-1)^2}\cdot\frac1{\ln^2\left(1+\frac2{x-1}\right)}<\frac12-\frac{2}{(x-1)^2}\cdot \frac{(x-1)^2}{4}=0&(\because (1))\\
&\Rightarrow\boxed{\frac1{\ln\left(1+\frac2{x-1}\right)}<\frac x2~\forall~ x>1}\\
\lim_{x\to\infty}f^\prime(x)&=\frac12-\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac2{t^2\ln^2\left(1+\frac2{t}\right)}=\frac12-\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac2{t^2\cdot\frac4{t^2}}=0\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Sorry, how did u get $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0$.

Comment: @karate_kid Actually in this *nice* example, we needed to expand $\ln(1+t)$ up to two terms. The takeaway is that you should always look for how many terms of the expansion are needed to get the correct limit. Here, had you expanded to just one term, you would have got the wrong limit which is $\frac12$.

Comment: I see what you did, then would it be possible to just set $x = 1/y$ and expand $\frac{1}{\ln\left(\frac{1/y+1}{1/y-1}\right)} = \frac{1}{\ln\left(\frac{1+y}{1-y}\right)}$ about $y = 0$ and take the higher order term which is $\frac{1}{2y} = \frac{x}{2}$ ?

Comment: @karate_kid If you are talking about expanding $\frac1{\ln\left(\frac{1+y}{1-y}\right)}$ about $y=0$, it doesn't seem possible for $f(0)$ doesn't exist. I suppose you are talking about doing $$\lim_{y\to0}\frac 1{2y}-\frac1{\ln(1+y)-\ln(1-y)}=\lim_{y\to0}\frac 1{2y}-\frac1{2y+O(y^3)}=0$$, which according to me is neither a good idea.

Comment: @karate_kid Because I was tempted to do $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac x2-\frac1{\ln\left(1+\frac2{x-1}\right)}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac x2-\frac1{\frac2{x-1}}=\frac12$$ and hence the substitution of $y\to\frac1x$ was a little overwork for me for I had confided in an answer without it, although a wrong one. Hence taking the LCM as done in my answer has the least possible chances of error and should be adopted as a general technique.

Comment: Thanks, once again !!!

Comment: @karate_kid If you are satisfied, then perhaps you can approve my answer by hovering to the left side of it(near the upvotes).